# При запуске seed значение env('DB_USERNAME) не совпадает в .env

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

```
В .env установлены следующие значения для пользователя:

APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:jkUuiJJr7k+TzJwOZUExhJ/Mdr4i3Jg=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=my-database
DB_USERNAME=my_user
DB_PASSWORD=123
```

На удаленном сервере запускаю seeds, выдает следующую ошибку:

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Seeded: SiteStringsTableSeeder**

```
class SiteStringsTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        // mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=1G --no-create-info=TRUE --user=root --default-character-set=utf8 "db_old" "sitestring" > db_old_sitestring.sql
        // mysql -uroot my_user < db_old_sitestring.sql
        $pass_if_pass =  env('DB_PASSWORD');
        $pass_if_pass =  $pass_if_pass ? ' -p'.$pass_if_pass.' ' : ' ';


        exec("mysql -u".env('DB_USERNAME', 'root').$pass_if_pass.
            env('DB_DATABASE', 'db')." < database/seeds/sitestrings_seed.sql");
    }
}
```

Причем здесь root, если в .env определен другой пользователь? Заранее спасибо за ответ

Comment: А ты уверен что у тебя файл .env там ? ведь если ты использовал git то он был в игноре

Comment: есть, я его только что в него заходил на сервере и проверял еще раз

Comment: Ну в любом случае, логично, что он его не находит, раз подставляет root. проверь имя файла еще раз.